# How to Map Users with Groups (IAM) with Organisation Unit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Related to AWS:
I've been trying to search for an answer about the Users and Groups that I have created using IAM (AWS), how can I map those Groups with the Organization Unit(s)?

For example: I have a Group called 'Developers' where Users (say 5 Users) are member of it.
Now, I have an Organization Unit of 'ApplicationsDevelopment&Services' where I need to give access to 'Developers'. Can I associate Groups with OUs, so that members of that Group get necessary access.
I have some policies (SCP) applied on that OU, to manage the access boundaries of Developers.
Please suggest if there is a way to do it or something else needs to be done like ActiveDirectory setup (whole new setup)?

Thank You,
Varun Gupta

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to have a look into AWS SSO (https://aws.amazon.com/single-sign-on/?nc1=h_ls). It comes with no additional cost, is enabled with one click and lets you easily assign cross-account role access to Groups/Users.

Going with an IAM Group which you like to have access to all accounts inside one OU, create roles inside those accounts with a trust relationship to the user/group account. You can use a CloudFormation StackSet to enroll the Stack on OU level. Allow `sts:AssumeRole` for the particular group, resource section pointing to the role you deployed through the StackSet (leave the account_id blank).

Then everyone inside the group should be able to assume the role and deployment of the cross-account role is centralized.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Org SCPs have account or OU scope, they are not for individual IAM users or roles. From [aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-service-control-policies-to-set-permission-guardrails-across-accounts-in-your-aws-organization/):

> Central security administrators use service control policies (SCPs) with AWS Organizations to establish controls that **all IAM principals** (users and roles) adhere to.

At the account level, a similar type of maximum permissions gourds on individual **users or roles** (not groups) can be set using [permission boundries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html). Thus, if you have any roles mapped to your uses through AD, you can look at attaching permissions boundaries to them. But, note that permissions boundaries are an advanced IAM topic, thus its not clear for me how exactly they would apply to your use-case.